# STRIPE.JS Error

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

[Stripe.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPn4P.png)
Trying to implement Stripe in a project and i keep getting this error 
Any idea what should i do ???

**Stripe is not defined fix or add /*global $*/**

----->   "stripe_card_token"=>"undefined"}}   <------

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  // Watch for a form submission:
  $("#form-submit-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    var error = false;
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();

    if (!error) {
      // Get the Stripe token:
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  }); // form submission

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    // Get a reference to the form:
    var f = $("#new_user");

    // Get the token from the response:
    var token = response.id;

    // Add the token to the form:
    f.append('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');

    // Submit the form:
    f.get(0).submit(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: How are you including stripe.js?
Where is your code throwing this error? Which line?
What do you get when you `console.log(Stripe)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your first error is from the linter you're using. You can add `/* global Stripe */` as the first line (depending on the linter you use).

Comment: Already fixed that now im getting and error | This customer has no attached payment source | ------ |  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)  |

Comment: You should console.log(response.error) to see if the token was actually created or if that failed.